# Cygwin: Error while converting tiff image to text

Tags: android, cygwin

I want to make business card scanner project with the help of tesseract ocr. I used this link  http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ReadMe

In this link I used Non-Windows mean cygwin to compile and run the tesseract ocr. Now the main problem is after make install command when I am trying to convert the tiff image to text using this command : **"tesseract eurotext.tif outputtext -l eng"**

But the cygwin command line give me the error like this:

```
  actual_tessdata_num_entries_<=TESSDATA_NUM_ENTRIES:Error:Assert failed:in file
  tessdatamanager.cpp, line 55
  Segmentation fault <core dumpes>
```

Please help me, I think I reached very near to my project. but something missing. any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct.  It sounds like your English definition file is bad.  Try this:

Per this link:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1647350

Try substituting this file:

- http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=eng.traineddata.gz

PS:
What does this have to do with "Android"?

Comment: Hi, Thanx for response paulsm. I used xp for that and Given link the process is for Linux. also I download and copy  eng.traineddata file into "C:\cygwin\usr\local\share\tessdata" but still have a same problem .please help.

Comment: hi Thanks very much . my code is perfect running. I download the traineddata file . but not this link .when I used this link and used eng.traineddata in my project . Its work . .thanku very much . .U made my day. again thanx.